# How to show list of locations on google map

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I am creating an iPhone application in which i need to fetch the latitude longitude from gps.Now i am calling update-location delegate method and adding new location to the array after that i need to show  all latitude longitude(locations ) on goggle map and the route between all locations.

Please help me out in showing the route.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you considered using [MapKit](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MapKit_Framework_Reference/_index.html), which is discussed in the [Location Awareness Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/MapKit/MapKit.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH3-SW1)?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you might do it with the GoogleMaps javascript api.

```
<style>
  #map_canvas {
    height: 190px;
    width: 300px;
    margin-top: 0.6em;
  }
</style>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=places"></script>
<div id="map_canvas" ></div>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">  
var latitude = 44.056389;
var longitude = -121.308056;

function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = { 
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(latitude,longitude),
          zoom: 9,
          streetViewControl: false,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),
          mapOptions);

        // Create a draggable marker which will later on be binded to a
        // Circle overlay.
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          map: map,
          position: new google.maps.LatLng(latitude,longitude),
          draggable: true
        });

        // Add a Circle overlay to the map.
        var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
            strokeColor: "#0000FF",
            strokeOpacity: 0.4,
            strokeWeight: 2,
            fillColor: "#0000FF",
            fillOpacity: 0.20,
            map: map,
            radius: 16000 // meters
        });

        circle.bindTo('center', marker, 'position');

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function() {
            var location = marker.getPosition();
            latitude = location.lat();
            longitude = location.lng();
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
          var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
          var location = place.geometry.location;
          map.setCenter(location);
          map.setZoom(9);  // Why 9? Because it looks good.
          marker.setPosition(location);
          latitude = location.lat();
          longitude = location.lng();
        });

      }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your concern but i need to apply this thing for ios can you please tell me for iphone

Comment: Opps, thought that it just used a web page inside the application like Google documents here: https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/tutorial-iphone

Comment: It seems to be like to show one source location to destination that i can do with the google direction api http://maps.google.com/maps?output=dragdir&saddr=%@&daddr=%@"....but i want to show the way point like i need to show from one location to destination by some waypoint .....

Comment: Might want to tag this with one of the Google-maps tags.  Might help get someone from that side.